# Term for place to post flyers

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a term for a physical place to post flyers?

Comment: By and large, the posting of [flyers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyposting) is illegal. So it's a bit odd to ask for names of places where you can "properly" post them.

Comment: From the linked article: "Flyposting is the act of placing advertising posters or flyers in illegal places." - in other words, that already implies there are place where it is not illegal to post them.

Comment: @Fumble: it’s certainly not illegal in general.  I’ve helped with publicising amateur plays and concerts, and a large part of that is wandering around towns and campuses working out on which notice-boards one *can* legitimately put up posters/flyers!

Comment: When we talk of posting flyers, the poster doesn't normally deal with and *pay* the owner of whatever he posts on. And there aren't many people or organisations willing to provide that space free. It's usually illegal anywhere around town, and I don't think college/youth club notice boards are what OP is thinking of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I’m not seeing why you think the OP is excluding those; but in any case, besides those, I’ve found supermarkets, coffee shops, bars, and churches very often have spots for flyers and posters for local events, and two cities I’ve lived in (one UK, one US) have also had some public places where it was legal to post flyers.  I’m sure it varies and may be different elsewhere, but in at least some places, it’s legal and fairly common.  Posting flyers ≠ flyposting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am asking for verbiage about english usage not a legal question.

Comment: @Pat: I'm only pointing it out because by the very nature of the legal position, any words you get are likely to be slang (or at least, *should* be).

Comment: @PPL: The legit ones are invariably called "noticeboards" in the UK, but ordinarily you don't see flyers on commercial ones - only in places like colleges where no-one cares much. Maybe this whole dispute just depends on your definition of "flyer", which I associate with, for example, fly-tipping. Most of the ones I see are on lamp-posts, walls, etc., and are generally regarded as littering/vandalism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- board
- bulletin board
- cork board
- announcement area
- community notice area
- notice board
- notice area
- message wall
- note board
- note wall
- news wall
- news board
- [poster kiosk](http://www.google.com/search?q=poster+kiosk+image)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply call it a *board* or *bulletin board*.

Comment: We were thinking about "bulletin board" but it gets long to repeatedly use "bulletin board". And "board" gets confused with lumber. (thus my searching for an alternative)

Answer (score 2):

You could use *billboard* or if you are in the UK, *hoarding.*

Comment: Both of these, to my understanding, suggest very large advertisements.  A big Coca-Cola ad goes on a billboard/hoarding (and takes up the whole of it), but the little poster for my amateur orchestra goes on a notice-board or bulletin-board (probably alongside a dozen other flyers there).

Comment: Never heard of "hoarding" before. Cool :-)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes call it a *Notice Board*, because that's where people also post lot's of "Lost and Founds," Advertisements, Soceity Informations, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is a German word (Litfaß column) for the short round pillars to place adverts on. Our schools German teacher always wanted it to become common in England (like kindergarten)

Answer (score 0):

Advertising column. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertising_column
Also morris column (French) or Litfaß column (German)